# How can I get my Json object from URL, Windows Phone 8.1 (C#)

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, webclient

Suppose I have this data:

```
{
    "A": "Z",
    "B": {
        "C": "Y",
        "D": "X"
    }
}
```

stored in [this](https://api.myjson.com/bins/2hxei) link.

now I want this data from my windows phone app during a button click.

```
private void login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //I want to read the json data here        
}
```

Previously I have tried `DownloadStringAsync` method of [WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203377/getting-json-string-from-url-in-windows-phone-8). But this class is no longer available in System.Net. I would like to know the place and documents where I can learn how to get and post data using url.

Thanks.

Comment: `HttpClient` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: private void login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        

            RunAsync().Wait();

        }
        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var webClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var json = webClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2hxei");
                
            }

        }


    }



Tried this code now how to test wether the object is recieved in var or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var uri = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/2hxei";
    var result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(client.DownloadData(uri));

    // result : {"A":"Z","B":{"C":"Y","D":"X"}}
}
```

btw. [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx) is definitely still available in .NET

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to use [Web Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx) (older) and want to use the newer [Http Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) instead, use the following code.

```
public static string GetJsonData()
{
    var promise = GetWebStringAsync("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2hxei");
    // do something else if needed
    var jsonData = promise.Result;
    return jsonData; //{"A":"Z","B":{"C":"Y","D":"X"}}
}

public static async Task<string> GetWebStringAsync(string uri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var stringTask = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return stringTask;
    }
}
```

Here, if you want, rather than doing `var stringTask = await client.GetStringAsync(uri)` you can also do `var jsonString= client.GetStringAsync(uri).Result`  directly. But you'll lose the benefits of `aynchronous` method there, and the call will be synchronous. The calling thread will wait there until response is received from the web call.

Comment: jw. can you provide a source to where it says the WebClient is deprecated?

Comment: @Meehow Though I remember seeing Web Client marked "deprecated" as part of some real documentation, I could not find that! Pretty odd! I have edited the answer and removed *deprecated* so that it doesn't misguide others! Thanks for pointing out.